How do I choose Cl during cruise flight with a given MTOM and variable S?
Currently I'm challenging myself to build an airplane from scratch. I have a background in (aeronautical) engineering but I have no experience in actually designing an aircraft from the ground up. (FYI: I want to build a flying wing - yes I know, I can already hear some of you asking why instead of a normal airplane but please just accept the fact that it's the most fun for me).
However, I am struggling to find a starting point. I figured it would be a good idea to start with the facts I have. Although not much, I know that:

The MTOM is going to be: $ m_{MTOM} \leq 250 \ \text{g} $ (for regulation reasons),
The cruise speed will (very roughly) be: $ v_{cruise} \approx [40 \dots 50] \ \frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}} = [11 \dots 14] \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$ (I'm going to propel it with a either a T4x2x3 or T4x2.5 propeller powered by a 2S Li-Ion battery and a 1404 3800 KV BLDC motor),
The plane should be as efficient as possible with a feasible but scientific design process.

To get started on designing a suitable wing I thought it would make sense to select a fitting airfoil first. I read a lot about flying wings and what stuck with me is that for an (unswept) flying wing I need an airfoil with reflex. Three candidates I came across are:

PW75,
E230 and
E186.

Now I ask myself: how do I select at what $c_l$ I fly during cruise? How do I translate it to the 3D $c_L$ in order to calculate the surface area $S$ while in steady, horizontal flight ($F_W = F_L$)? What is the best planform for the resulting surface area $S$ to lift my plane? I.e. how do I choose $AR$ or $\lambda$ , $\varphi$ (sweep angle), etc.? Is this even the right starting point?
Edit 1: I settled myself on all types of flying wings, including swept flying wings.
Edit 2: I tried to make the question more constrained. So you don't have to list the entire aerodynamic design process of an airplane as an answer in order to answer it.

You mean something like a Northrop?

I plan on designing an unswept flying wing. More like the  Backstrom EPB-1. At RC scale it would probably come close to the Nano Goblin.

Update: yes, something like a Northrop as well!

This is an attempt to answer my own question.
From what I have learned so far, there are generally more ways than one to approach this problem. Generally speaking it will be an iterative process though.
To start working on my UAV I began to estimate $c_L$ in order to be able to calculate a planform $S$ that will lift the plane. For that we have to pick $c_l$, so the 2D lift coefficient, first. As @MaxPower suggested I started with a reasonable average $c_l$. In this case I start with $c_l = 0.3$. This results in $S = 0.0805 \ \text{m^2}$ at a cruise speed of $v_c = 13 \ \text{m/s}$ for the given $m_{MTOM} = 0.25 \ \text{kg}$. To get to $c_L$, again there is more ways than one, I used the equation in the top left corner of the table in this answer by @PeterKämpf. There is also a different approach by Lee Nicolai as @AeroAndy mentioned. I used the first one since it takes more variables into account, which is probably overkill in this application.
Since this approach uses more variables, you also have to have a clearer image of your plane in mind. In other words we need to know what aspect ratio ($AR$ or $\lambda$) to use and to what extend the wing will be swept (back) (sweep angle $\varphi$). As @MaxPower mentioned, it makes sense to use the highest feasible aspect ratio to minimize the induced drag (more specifically the induced drag coefficient). Consider @PeterKämpfs answer to see why $AR$ only influences the coefficient not the induced drag force directly. Since I will be 3D printing my plane (I am aware of skin friction and will handle this problem with post processing, etc.) I am constrained by the build volume of my printer and amount of segments the wing will consist of. I calculated different sets of wing spans and chord lengths for a rectangular wing planform and came to the conclusion that $b = 0.695 \ \text{m}$ and $c = 0.116 \ \text{m}$ at $S = 0.0805 \ \text{m^2}$, so $AR = 6$ seems feasible as a first iteration.
The sweep angle $\varphi$ is a bit more tricky however. Especially with flying wings since it's used for more than just having less drag at transonic speeds like in usual aircraft. In their book "Tailless aircraft in theory and practice" by K. Nickel and M. Wohlfahrt the authors give a lot of information regarding wing sweep. As, for many things, there is no ideal sweep angle. This is a bit outside the scope for this answer, however there is a trade off between efficiency of the control surfaces, directional stability, stall behavior, dutch roll tendency, etc.
This is a starting point to refine and iterate the planform.
Please leave a comment if there is something you disagree with or if I made a mistake, etc.
Edit: As a starting point I use a sweep angle of $\varphi = 15 \ \text{°}$. Now, I also try to find a more optimal planform by deviating from a rectangular wing to a trapezoidal wing. This is done by varying the taper ratio. This is also outside this scope. However, Nickel and Wohlfahrt come to the conclusion that the lower the taper ratio ($l_{tip} < l_{root}$) the worse the stall behavior. I start with a taper ratio of $\frac{l_{tip}}{l_{root}} = 0.8$. This is also closely linked to the sweep angle $\varphi$.

You might find Lee Nicolai's white paper "Estimating R/C Model Aerodynamics and Performance" a useful guide and reference. Look under "series resources/design event resources" at saeaerodesign.com

Thanks for the resource! I’m currently reading “Schwanzlose Flugzeuge:
Ihre Auslegung und ihre Eigenschaften”. It’s obviously in german but I can recommend it to anyone stumbling over this post. I’m learning a lot. Hope to some day be finally able to answer this question.

This is a great resource, however I'm finding myself already struggling at the basics. It feels to me kind of like the chicken or the egg problem to find the right planform area $S$, $c_l$ and appropriate wing loading $\zeta$. But to know how to get from $c_{l\alpha}$ to $c_{l\alpha}$ is huge. Also in the white paper the equation for $c_L$ is only valid for unswept wings. Do you know if it is still valid for small sweep angles e.g. up to 15 ° or even 20 °?

@eckh_ma, in their textbook, Fundamentals of Aicraft and Airship Design, Volume 1, Nicolai and Carichner assert a simple adjustment to the zero sweep lift curve slope fits empirical data well. For AR > 6, simply multiply the zero sweep slope by the cosine of the quarter chord (or maximum thickness line, if much different) sweep. For AR < 6 multiple by the square root of same.  This is in section 2.7, p. 44.

Thank you so much!

Also in my 2nd comment it should of course say:
"But to know how to get from $c_{l\alpha}$ to $c_{L\alpha}$ is huge."

I'd start calculating the lift curve created by the wing. It can be simply estimated from the 2D curve (the one of the airfoil) using for example the subsonic equation A2 that you find in the appendix of this NACA report:

In this equation a$_o$ is the slope of the 2D airfoil your wing is built upon; A is the aspect ratio and $\Lambda$ is the sweep angle; units of measurement are given at the beginning of the report. Use the correct Reynolds number when you choose the 2D airfoil plots. The maximum lift coefficient of your wing is also related to the one of the airfoil it is built upon and can be estimated with the following equation:
$C_{L_{max}}=0.9C_{l_{max}}cos\Lambda$
Obviously this equation doesn't consider any high-lift device.


What is the best planform for the resulting surface area S to lift my plane? I.e. how do I choose AR, λ, etc.?

You can play with the parameters in that equation to see how the lift changes accordingly. Anyway the biggest limitation of wing geometry is going to arise from the trim analysis (see later).


how do I select at what $C_l$ I fly during cruise?

The target lift is the one where your plane is going to fly the most. This really depends on how you are going to fly it. Once you have defined the lift $L$, you can get the relevant coefficient simply using its definition:  $C_L=\frac{L}{½\rho V² S}$. Obviously you have to check that your wing can deliver enough lift to takeoff, land and manoeuvre as well.


Is this even the right starting point?

Afterwards I'd perform a longitudinal trim and stability analysis: this answer should contain all you need for that; just set the contribution from the tailplane and the fuselage to zero (since you don't have them).

From the trim analysis you'll get that changing the pitching moment of the wing is the only way to trim your airplane: its value and its variation with the deflection of the control surfaces can be estimated with the methods contained in the USAF STABILITY AND CONTROL DATCOM (chapter 4.1.4 and 6.1.5 respectively);
From the longitudinal stability analysis you'll simply get that the CG must be in front of the quarter chord point.

As said, you can use the results from this last step together with the results from the lift's calculation to revise/design the planform of the wing: airplane design is an iterative process.

Chapter 4.1.5 of the DATCOM can be used to estimate the wing drag and therefore the needed power. I'd use a rear-mounted propeller since this location stabilises the aircraft in pitch and yaw.

Finally you can do a lateral trim and stability analysis to design the vertical tailplane.

Thank you very much for your answer! I understand that you want me to basically play with the subsonic equations in the second figure in the answer you quoted. Is capital lambda the same as the lower case one (taper angle)?
What are good ways to calculate a factor for Cl for take off and landing once I settled on a cruise Cl?
Do you know a good resource to learn about lateral trim and stability analysis?
I would also appreciate a source for why a rear prop stabilizes in pitch and yaw.
I'm new to this page so please point out if this is too much for a comment, etc.

I'd suggest some standard "general airplane design" textbook, like the one by Raymer or Roskam or Torenbeek. Note that those are all textbooks about full-scale airplanes: all methods/equations based on statistics are therefore strictly valid only for that class of airplanes (MTOW or CG estimation for example). Anyway what is based on physics/aerodynamics is still valid also for model airplanes (lift or drag or stability estimation for example). The DATCOM contains too methods to estimate the wing $C_L$ for straight subsonic wings, you can use it instead of the equation in the other answer.

Thanks! I will look into it.

Sorry, the capital Lambda is actually the aspect ratio. I did not convert the equations fully to that strange US habit of using different symbols when adopting equations.

Thank very much for clarifying @PeterKämpf

@PeterKämpf, I am kind of going in circles with this equation. These are some questions I have:

What exactly is this equation calculating? $c_{L \alpha 3D}$?
| 2. And is this supposed to be inserted into the equation for $c_L$?
| 3. Also is the capital L in the index not already saying it's the 3D lift coefficient (and vice versa for 2D)?

I would greatly appreciate some help because I am unfortunately not getting plausible data.

@eckh_ma I guess you mean the lift curve slope equation in the linked answer. You can simplify things by leaving out the Mach and sweep terms for your flying wing. The result is the derivative of the lift coefficient over the angle of attack in radians. Since it uses aspect ratio, it is for 3D lift. If you tell me your parameters and results, I may be able to help more.

@PeterKämpf, Exactly, sorry for not specifying better what I'm actually referring to. I fixed it now. It was a mixture of sleep deprivation and not converting degrees to radians... What I'm curious about now though, is why the difference between $c_L$ and $c_l$ is so small from what I calculated. And why $c_L$ is bigger than $c_l$ for every $\alpha$ (in other words $c_{L, \alpha} > c_{l, \alpha}$). Because I read quite often in the literature the the lift coefficient of a 3D wing is often smaller than its section lift coefficient. My parameters:  $AR=6$, $\varphi_m =0.262$, $Ma=0.04$, $\nu=0$.

@eckh_ma I have no idea how you calculate the 2D lift curve slope. It is about 2π plus some thickness correction. The 3D lift curve slope always has an aspect ratio related correction factor which is less than 1.

@PeterKämpf, Oh, I just used $c_{l, \alpha} = 2 \pi$ for the 2D lift curve slope. Is that not correct? So it's true that the lift curve slope for 3D, $c_{L, \alpha}$, is in fact larger than the 2D lift curve slope, $c_{l, \alpha}$, right?

@eckh_ma No, it always is smaller. Look at what aspect ratio does to the 2π in the 3D lift curve slope equation: It is always adding a factor of less than one.

@eckh_ma: chapter 4.1.3 (from page 494 of the pdf) of the USAF DATCOM contains everything you need.

@PeterKämpf, Okay that checks out with what I read. It was an error in my calculation (again)... It was very hard to find the (subtle) error. Thank you for your patience! However, I'm not quite sure what equation we are talking about now. Because in this answer in the equation for $c_{L, \alpha}$ in the top left of the table I'm not seeing $AR$ affecting $2 \pi$ (or $\pi$ for that matter) in the way you are describing. I think I'm misunderstanding...

@sophit, Thanks!

@sophit, As I'm reading your answer again, one question still remains: I agree with " [...] get the relevant coefficient simply using its definition: $c_L = \frac{L}{\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 S}$." however, this still leaves me with two unknowns: $c_L$ AND $S$. I guess this highlights fairly well what I meant with "the chicken or the egg problem" when I commented AeroAndys answer. To know what $c_L$ I'm going to need, I need to know what surface area $S$ I require to lift the plane. But to know that, I need to know $c_L$ again and so on...

@eckh_ma You try to be the first airplane designer who does not need to iterate the solution? Please give up on that illusion! Pick one value, see where it gets you, improve the pick in the next iteration and so on. Regarding the top left equation: You do see AR in it, don't you? Next, enter the formula in a spreadsheet and calculate it for different ARs. What do you see?

@PeterKämpf, I'm sorry but I don't see where I said that I don't need to iterate. The question for me is how do I iterate and where do I start. Also, I struggle with judging the current iteration based on proven criteria because of missing experience and knowledge. That's the whole reason I turned to this website. I'm sorry if I made it seem like I was looking for some shortcut noone before me has ever found.

@PeterKämpf, Regarding the top left equation: I did evaluate it for different ARs. I see what it does. I'm just confused about how you see that "It is always adding a factor of less than one" at a glance. Because I'm not able to tell at first. I'm also still not sure about what you mean by "Look at what aspect ratio does to the $2 \pi$ in the 3D lift curve slope equation" because there is no $2 \pi$ in the top left equation. I hope you can help me resolve the confusion. Thank you for taking your time to help random people on the Internet learn about aeronautical engineering!

@eckh_ma: I expanded the section relative to the 3D lift, now it should be much clearer and easier to follow. The Northrop was based on a NACA 65-019, I'd start with that.

@eckh_ma Calculate the lift slope for an infinite aspect ratio. You will see that when you shorten the fraction properly, the equation is equal to π divided by ½. Which is equal to 2π in my book.

Thank you both so much @sophit and @PeterKämpf!

You state a plank wing but then go on to ask about planform and airfoil options, a plank is a flat rectangle.
So in general: Start with a reasonable average Cl for the class of airfoil you are using to get an approximate required wing area for basic structural design. If you use a pulling propeller the air flow will add airflow over the wing slightly increasing lift.
For subsonic aerodynamics an elliptical planform(more precisely elliptical lift distribution) is considered the most efficient, with the highest aspect ratio practical for the structural limits of materials, airfoil thickness ratio(bending and torsion strengths), construction methods, and mass distribution(eg Tanks/electric batteries inside wings vs fuselage). This minimizes induced drag. However, this is difficult to stabilize in a flying wing form factor, swept wings/delta are preferred for flying wings because the pitch control is easier (effectively blending a wing and tail together).
Use the Cl that occurs at the angle of attack which generates the best lift-to-drag ratio for your complete wing (The 2-dimensional airfoil optimum is minimum parasite drag, whole wing is induced drag plus parasite). Then scale the whole wing slightly up or down from the original area approximation to get the required total lift at the desired cruise speed. The best L/D can be obtained from a drag polar if you have accurate simulation or wind tunnel data that can be adjusted for Reynolds number.
Note this method does not necessarily account for other characteristics that may be desired such as takeoff and landing performance(including crosswind), maneuvering and gust safety factors(eg stall warning and spin recovery), oscillations, taxi-area wingspan limits, etc.

I appreciate your answer, thanks! I thought a "plank" referred to any unswept wing planform. I guess it also rules out taper. I'm going to rephrase the question.
I also thought of an elliptical planform or any planform with an elliptical circulation distribution. What do you think are reasons that the nano goblin doesn't have an elliptical planform besides ease of manufacturing?
Use the Cl that occurs at the angle of attack with the lift-to-drag ratio for your complete wing.
I would appreciate if you could elaborate this point since I don't fully understand it.

@eckh_ma That sentance was broken, I have edited it. …the Cl that occurs at the angle of attack which generates the best lift-to-drag ratio for your complete wing. So find the angle with the best lift to drag for your chosen wing, then calculate the cofficient of lift for that exact configuration. Finally use that Cl to scale the wing area to match your design operating weight. This is a somewhat iterative approach which may take a few cycles if there is a large scaling factor such as converting from small windtunnel models to human size aircraft.

Thank you very much! I'm still in the process of actually trying to do all the steps that you talked about (besides university and working) so that I can get a better understanding about everything.

So from what I understand you want me to: 1. Choose an average $c_l$ | 2. Convert $c_l$ to $c_L$ | 3. Calculate $S$ at desired cruise speed $v_c$ | 4. Redo the steps with the $c_l$ for best $\frac{L}{D}$. Is that correct?

@eckh_ma The order of steps is a matter of different perspectives. A builder starts at the foundation of a structure and finishes with the roof, because the bottom must support the top. An architect may start at the top with the required useful load because that determines the required strength and mass of the upper structure, the mass of the upper structure is required to calculate the load on the lower structure. To start engineering from the bottom would require many extra iterations. Opposite order for the same physical reason: the bottom must support the top. Airplane design is similar.

@eckh_ma regarding your old comment about the planforms and nano goblin. There is more to aerodynamics than simple efficiency. Behavior in adverse conditions is a major consideration. stalling at the wing root first is preferred to stalling near the tip or all at once. Ease of correct construction is a safety issue. The Reynolds number is very important, what is the scale of your design, 1 meter aircraft will behave very different from 10 meter at the same airspeed due to the boundary layer condition and relative boundary thickness changing the effective aerodynamic shape of the airfoil.

That's a good point! Can you please elaborate on "Ease of correct construction is a safety issue."? | I know that the Reynolds number is pretty important, however I only see it being factored it in when choosing the appropriate plot for $c_l$ vs. $\alpha$. From my point of view I still can't get behind the reasoning of $AR$ of the nano goblin. Is it really only that low because of maneuverability and behavior in adverse conditions? Do you think the final $AR$ is based on simulations or prototyping or both? What would you change about the planform of the nano goblin if anything?
